# Не могу получить Access Token от VK

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, xamarin, oauth2, token

Проблема: моё приложение на Android (пишу я на Xamarin) после авторизаций (через OAuth 2.0) переходит по URL (https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html), и у меня выводится только текст аля "Пожалуйста, не копируйте данные из адресной строки...". Также после этого моя программа не получает `access_token` (проверил через точку остонова).

Кусок кода

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
            clientId: "Id клиента, который запомнили на прошлом шаге",
            scope: "friends,video,groups",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri ("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html"));
        auth.AllowCancel = true;
        auth.Completed += (s, ee) => {
            if (!ee.IsAuthenticated) {
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
                builder.SetMessage ("Not Authenticated");
                builder.SetPositiveButton ("Ok", (o, e) => { });
                builder.Create().Show();
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Только недавно с таким сталкивался. Что бы получать токен нормально нужно в библиотеку вписать свой app_id в класс VKSdk.
Еще возможны проблемы с сохранением access_token на устройстве.

---

Дополню. Описанное в этом ответе ошибочно и следует из неправильного подключения библиотеки.

Comment: Но здесь я не использовал VKSdk я через OAuth 2.0 делал . И в clientId: "стоит мой app id"

Answer (score 0):

После перенаправления на https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html в параметрах запроса передаётся не access token, а authorization codе. Именно Authorization Code Grant поток является потоком по умолчанию в VK (см. [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/oauth_dialog) на response_type).

В случае если вы хотите использовать Implicit Grant поток (подразумевающий отправку именно access token), используйте token как response_type.

Конкретно в данном коде (при условии того что вы верно зарегистрировали приложения в dev.vk - проверьте используемый тип приложения, вероятнее всего вам нужен standalone) после перенаправления на blank.html вы получите в параметрах Authorization Code который ещё нужно обменять на access token (подробно данный вид авторизации рассмотрен [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites)). И только уже получив access token вы сможете осуществлять запросы к API.